# What does "N.B. software" refer to in a /etc/apt/sources.list?

Tags: apt, software-sources, canonical

In a sources.list I see these comments:

```
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
```

Anyone have an idea what "**N.B.**" refers to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene, N.B. in short means "pay attention" or "take notice". Therefore, the comment is telling you you should take note the software in that repository is not supported by Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

"N.B." (Nota Bene) is a Latin form, in English you can read it as "Note well".

In this case, the `sources.list` file contains just a heads up for the users about the repository(ies). And the given note is self-explanatory i think as the Universe repository contains mostly the community contributions.

Comment: Thanks, I've been using Debian and Ubuntu for a long time, just wasn't familiar enough with the Latin notation to realize what **N.B.** was referring to.

Comment: @Jonwithnoh Yeah, just a heads up like i said :)